# Ubuntu 17.04 installer unable to find SSD (only HD available) on a MacBookPro11,1

Tags: boot, macbook-pro, 17.04

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 17.04 as the sole OS on a MacBookPro11,1 using a Live USB. It previously run only Ubuntu 14.04.

Initially when using the Live USB I was unable to get it to boot as after the initial menu asking whether I want to install or simply try Ubuntu it produced the following error message:

```
(initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system
```

And it couldn't go any further. However after playing with the boot settings a bit I am able to get the Live USB to run using the options: `acpi=off` and `nodmraid`.

But now Ubuntu is unable to see the Macs build-in SSD to allow me to install it. How can I get Ubuntu to detect this?

fdisk cannot see the SSD:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1462083584 bytes, 2855632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 29.9 GiB, 32078036992 bytes, 62652416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x782a20f2

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        0 2964415 2964416  1.4G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       84608   89215    4608  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

If I list the hardware available I can see the SSD does appear under the PCI devices. I'm not sure what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I still don't know what caused this very odd behaviour. However I was able to fix it simply by using the OS X Recovery Mode and re-installing OS X (to a USB stick in my case) once the installer reached the point of restarting the machine everything started working normally again. I was then able to install Ubuntu 17.04 without a hitch (which works really nicely the Mac).

If anyone knows what the OS X installer did to fix this/what the cause was I would love to know.